# Multiple reclassification using RasterCalc in QGIS

Tags: qgis, reclassify

Is there any way to perform multiple reclassification using RasterCalc?

For example reclassifying value 1 to 100 in map Map can be written as:

```
eq([Map]@1, 1, 100)
```

But if there are multiple values to reclassify in one operation, how can I do it?
For example reclassifying value 1 to 100 AND 2 to 200 in map Map.

```
eq([Map]@1, 1, 100), eq([Map]@1, 2, 200) //<-This does not work!!
```

Please give me a advice.

Comment: Not sure that it is possible with RasterCalc. But you may try this: eq([eq([Map]@1, 1, 100)]@1, 2, 200)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed SEXTANTE and SAGA/GRASS then you could also just use those functions.

Both come with a reclassification function (r.reclass in GRASS and "Reclassify Grid Values"), which support so called rules. In a "rules file" you could simply specify multiple reclassifications.